# Al deserializar la respuesta de un servicio soap desde c# obtengo null

Tags: c#, soap

actualmente recibo esta respuesta de un servicio soap (sacado de SoapUI), pero cuando lo pruebo desde net.6 solo obtengo un nulo.
La parte de la autentificación me funciona y me devuelve el token pero la consulta no. Tuve q cambiar de System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatStyle.Rpc a System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatStyle.Document

`<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"`

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <consultaCodecosPrecintoResponse xmlns="http://codecos.portic.net">
         <consultaCodecosPrecintoReturn>
            <codigoError>0</codigoError>
            <listaCodecosPrecinto>
               <item>
                  <fechaOperacion>202207200700</fechaOperacion>
                  <matricula>SZLU9703727</matricula>
                  <matriculaCamion>2126CYY</matriculaCamion>
                  <nifEmisor>ESB62120175</nifEmisor>
                  <precintoNaviera/>
                  <precintoTerminal>2782030</precintoTerminal>
                  <terminal>ESB62120175</terminal>
                  <tipoCodeco>CODECOI08</tipoCodeco>
               </item>
               <item>
                  <fechaOperacion>202207201232</fechaOperacion>
                  <matricula>SZLU9703727</matricula>
                  <matriculaCamion>2126CYY</matriculaCamion>
                  <nifEmisor>ESB62120175</nifEmisor>
                  <precintoNaviera>278203ESBCN</precintoNaviera>
                  <precintoTerminal/>
                  <terminal>ESB62120175</terminal>
                  <tipoCodeco>CODECOE07</tipoCodeco>
               </item>
               <item>
                  <fechaOperacion>202207201232</fechaOperacion>
                  <matricula>SZLU9703727</matricula>
                  <matriculaCamion>2126CYY</matriculaCamion>
                  <nifEmisor>ESB62120175</nifEmisor>
                  <precintoNaviera>278203ESBCN</precintoNaviera>
                  <precintoTerminal/>
                  <terminal>ESB62120175</terminal>
                  <tipoCodeco>CODECOE07</tipoCodeco>
               </item>
               <item>
                  <fechaOperacion>202207200700</fechaOperacion>
                  <matricula>SZLU9703727</matricula>
                  <matriculaCamion>2126CYY</matriculaCamion>
                  <nifEmisor>ESB62120175</nifEmisor>
                  <precintoNaviera/>
                  <precintoTerminal>2782030</precintoTerminal>
                  <terminal>ESB62120175</terminal>
                  <tipoCodeco>CODECOI08</tipoCodeco>
               </item>
            </listaCodecosPrecinto>
         </consultaCodecosPrecintoReturn>
      </consultaCodecosPrecintoResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Esta es la clase que se ha generado agregando la referencia de servicio desde Visual Studio 2022 http://app.portic.net:80/cxfaxis/services/ConsultaCodecosPrecinto?wsdl

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     Este código fue generado por una herramienta.
//
//     Los cambios en este archivo podrían causar un comportamiento incorrecto y se perderán si
//     se vuelve a generar el código.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace APB.API.PIF.CONSULTAPRECINTOS
{


    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.3")]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace = "http://codecos.portic.net", ConfigurationName = "APB.API.PIF.CONSULTAPRECINTOS.ConsultaCodecosPrecinto")]
    public interface ConsultaCodecosPrecinto
    {

        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "", ReplyAction = "*")]
        [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(Style = System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatStyle.Document, SupportFaults = true)]
        [return: System.ServiceModel.MessageParameterAttribute(Name = "consultaCodecosPrecintoReturn")]
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<APB.API.PIF.CONSULTAPRECINTOS.ConsultaCodecosPrecintoReturn> consultaCodecosPrecintoAsync(APB.API.PIF.CONSULTAPRECINTOS.ConsultaCodecosPrecintoRequest req);

        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "", ReplyAction = "*")]
        [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(Style = System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatStyle.Document, SupportFaults = true)]
        [return: System.ServiceModel.MessageParameterAttribute(Name = "autenticarReturn")]
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> autenticarAsync(APB.API.PIF.CONSULTAPRECINTOS.AutenticarRequest request);
    }





    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.3")]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://codecos.portic.net")]
    public partial class ConsultaCodecosPrecintoRequest
    {

        private string fechaInicioField;

        private string matriculaField;

        private string paisNifEmpresaField;

        private string tokenField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = true, Order = 0)]
        public string fechaInicio
        {
            get
            {
                return this.fechaInicioField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.fechaInicioField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = true, Order = 1)]
        public string matricula
        {
            get
            {
                return this.matriculaField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.matriculaField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = true, Order = 2)]
        public string paisNifEmpresa
        {
            get
            {
                return this.paisNifEmpresaField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.paisNifEmpresaField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = true, Order = 3)]
        public string token
        {
            get
            {
                return this.tokenField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.tokenField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.3")]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://codecos.portic.net")]
    public partial class AutenticarRequest
    {

        private string codigoUsuarioField;

        private string paisNifEmpresaField;

        private string passwordField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = true, Order = 0)]
        public string codigoUsuario
        {
            get
            {
                return this.codigoUsuarioField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.codigoUsuarioField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = true, Order = 1)]
        public string paisNifEmpresa
        {
            get
            {
                return this.paisNifEmpresaField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.paisNifEmpresaField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = true, Order = 2)]
        public string password
        {
            get
            {
                return this.passwordField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.passwordField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.3")]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://codecos.portic.net")]
    public partial class CodecoPrecinto
    {

        private string fechaOperacionField;

        private string matriculaField;

        private string matriculaCamionField;

        private string nifEmisorField;

        private string precintoNavieraField;

        private string precintoTerminalField;

        private string terminalField;

        private string tipoCodecoField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = true, Order = 0)]
        public string fechaOperacion
        {
            get
            {
                return this.fechaOperacionField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.fechaOperacionField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = true, Order = 1)]
        public string matricula
        {
            get
            {
                return this.matriculaField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.matriculaField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = true, Order = 2)]
        public string matriculaCamion
        {
            get
            {
                return this.matriculaCamionField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.matriculaCamionField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = true, Order = 3)]
        public string nifEmisor
        {
            get
            {
                return this.nifEmisorField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.nifEmisorField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = true, Order = 4)]
        public string precintoNaviera
        {
            get
            {
                return this.precintoNavieraField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.precintoNavieraField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = true, Order = 5)]
        public string precintoTerminal
        {
            get
            {
                return this.precintoTerminalField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.precintoTerminalField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = true, Order = 6)]
        public string terminal
        {
            get
            {
                return this.terminalField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.terminalField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = true, Order = 7)]
        public string tipoCodeco
        {
            get
            {
                return this.tipoCodecoField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.tipoCodecoField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.3")]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://codecos.portic.net")]
    public partial class ConsultaCodecosPrecintoReturn
    {
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://codecos.portic.net")]
        private string codigoErrorField;
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://codecos.portic.net")]
        private CodecoPrecinto[] listaCodecosPrecintoField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = true, Order = 0)]
        public string codigoError
        {
            get
            {
                return this.codigoErrorField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.codigoErrorField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = true, Order = 1)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("item", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = false)]
        public CodecoPrecinto[] listaCodecosPrecinto
        {
            get
            {
                return this.listaCodecosPrecintoField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.listaCodecosPrecintoField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.3")]
    public interface ConsultaCodecosPrecintoChannel : APB.API.PIF.CONSULTAPRECINTOS.ConsultaCodecosPrecinto, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel
    {
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.3")]
    public partial class ConsultaCodecosPrecintoClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<APB.API.PIF.CONSULTAPRECINTOS.ConsultaCodecosPrecinto>, APB.API.PIF.CONSULTAPRECINTOS.ConsultaCodecosPrecinto
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Implemente este método parcial para configurar el punto de conexión de servicio.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="serviceEndpoint">El punto de conexión para configurar</param>
        /// <param name="clientCredentials">Credenciales de cliente</param>
        static partial void ConfigureEndpoint(System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials clientCredentials);

        public ConsultaCodecosPrecintoClient() :
                base(ConsultaCodecosPrecintoClient.GetDefaultBinding(), ConsultaCodecosPrecintoClient.GetDefaultEndpointAddress())
        {
            this.Endpoint.Name = EndpointConfiguration.ConsultaCodecosPrecinto.ToString();
            ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
        }

        public ConsultaCodecosPrecintoClient(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration) :
                base(ConsultaCodecosPrecintoClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(endpointConfiguration), ConsultaCodecosPrecintoClient.GetEndpointAddress(endpointConfiguration))
        {
            this.Endpoint.Name = endpointConfiguration.ToString();
            ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
        }

        public ConsultaCodecosPrecintoClient(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration, string remoteAddress) :
                base(ConsultaCodecosPrecintoClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(endpointConfiguration), new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(remoteAddress))
        {
            this.Endpoint.Name = endpointConfiguration.ToString();
            ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
        }

        public ConsultaCodecosPrecintoClient(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) :
                base(ConsultaCodecosPrecintoClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(endpointConfiguration), remoteAddress)
        {
            this.Endpoint.Name = endpointConfiguration.ToString();
            ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
        }

        public ConsultaCodecosPrecintoClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) :
                base(binding, remoteAddress)
        {
        }



        [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<APB.API.PIF.CONSULTAPRECINTOS.ConsultaCodecosPrecintoReturn> APB.API.PIF.CONSULTAPRECINTOS.ConsultaCodecosPrecinto.consultaCodecosPrecintoAsync(APB.API.PIF.CONSULTAPRECINTOS.ConsultaCodecosPrecintoRequest req)
        {
            return base.Channel.consultaCodecosPrecintoAsync(req);
        }

        public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<APB.API.PIF.CONSULTAPRECINTOS.ConsultaCodecosPrecintoReturn> consultaCodecosPrecintoAsync(APB.API.PIF.CONSULTAPRECINTOS.ConsultaCodecosPrecintoRequest req)
        {
            return base.Channel.consultaCodecosPrecintoAsync(req);
        }




        public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> autenticarAsync(APB.API.PIF.CONSULTAPRECINTOS.AutenticarRequest request)
        {
            return base.Channel.autenticarAsync(request);
        }

        public virtual System.Threading.Tasks.Task OpenAsync()
        {
            return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.FromAsync(((System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject)(this)).BeginOpen(null, null), new System.Action<System.IAsyncResult>(((System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject)(this)).EndOpen));
        }

        public virtual System.Threading.Tasks.Task CloseAsync()
        {
            return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.FromAsync(((System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject)(this)).BeginClose(null, null), new System.Action<System.IAsyncResult>(((System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject)(this)).EndClose));
        }

        private static System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding GetBindingForEndpoint(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration)
        {
            if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.ConsultaCodecosPrecinto))
            {
                System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding result = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
                result.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
                result.ReaderQuotas = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max;
                result.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
                result.AllowCookies = true;
                return result;
            }
            throw new System.InvalidOperationException(string.Format("No se pudo encontrar un punto de conexión con el nombre \"{0}\".", endpointConfiguration));
        }

        private static System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress GetEndpointAddress(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration)
        {
            if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.ConsultaCodecosPrecinto))
            {
                return new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("http://app.portic.net/cxfaxis/services/ConsultaCodecosPrecinto");
            }
            throw new System.InvalidOperationException(string.Format("No se pudo encontrar un punto de conexión con el nombre \"{0}\".", endpointConfiguration));
        }

        private static System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding GetDefaultBinding()
        {
            return ConsultaCodecosPrecintoClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(EndpointConfiguration.ConsultaCodecosPrecinto);
        }

        private static System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress GetDefaultEndpointAddress()
        {
            return ConsultaCodecosPrecintoClient.GetEndpointAddress(EndpointConfiguration.ConsultaCodecosPrecinto);
        }

        public enum EndpointConfiguration
        {

            ConsultaCodecosPrecinto,
        }
    }
}
```

Y mi código es el siguiente, no da error, pero me devuelve nulo, estoy haciendo algo mal?

```
public async Task<ConsultaCodecosPrecintoReturn> ConsultaCodecosPrecinto(string fecha, string matricula)
        {

            string token = await AutenticarServicio();

            try
            {
                var response = await _proxyCW.consultaCodecosPrecintoAsync(
                new ConsultaCodecosPrecintoRequest()
                {
                    fechaInicio = fecha,                     
                    matricula = matricula ,                     
                    paisNifEmpresa = _config["Credentials:NifEmpresa"],
                    token = token
                });


                return response;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var error = ex;
                return null;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Me vas a disculpar, pero nadie en su sano juicio va a revisar todo ese código. Me tocó consumir bastantes WS hace varios años. El principal problema se da porque la implementación de estos es incorrecta, la mayoría hechos en java y como el SoapUI también está hecho en java entre ellos no tienen problema.

Comment: Lo que debes hacer es sniffear tu solicitud (creo que telerik tenía una herramienta) o incluso dentro del mismo código imprimir el XML que estas enviando, con ello comparas contra lo que envía SoapUI. Finalmente en .net existen varias configuración y atributos (decoradores) que te permitirán modificar la salida XML para que te quede igual a lo que hace el SoapUI